# Creating custom log levels in apache log4j in Java code, Logger.log() method signature varies from official documentation

Tags: java, maven, logging, log4j

I have gone through this question:

[how to add custom logging level in log4j](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44924696/how-to-add-custom-logging-level-in-log4j)

and also the official log4j documentation here:

https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/customloglevels.html

I do not have log4j.xml in my code, and I am trying to implement it in Java code itself. However, while doing that, I am facing a problem where the signature of the Logger.log() method is coming different from what is written.

According to the documentation, if I write this piece of code, I will get a custom log level which I will be able to use in other parts of my code:

```
final Level CUSTOM = Level.forName("CUSTOM", 550);

final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger();
logger.log(CUSTOM, "a custom message");
```

According to the Javadocs (https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-api/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/Logger.html), the Logger.log() method also accepts a Level object as its first argument. I have imported the following Maven dependency in my project, since this feature is supported only from version 2.x:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.1</version>
</dependency>
```

I had also tried with this dependency:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>2.13.0</version>
</dependency>
```

But the effect was the same, which is when I try to write the logger.log() code, Intellisense tells me that the only versions of this method supported are those which contain a Priority object as the first argument, not Level. If I try to forcibly include the Level object, I get a compilation error. Please tell me which Maven dependency would give me the desired Level object as the first parameter of the logger.log() method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/maven-artifacts.html) you need two dependencies

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.13.3</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.13.3</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: I removed the earlier dependencies and added these two as you have suggested. However, even after doing a Maven update of my project, the Logger.log() method signature still contains only Priority object as the first argument, not Level object.

Comment: I tried doing that, but I am importing an instance of Logger using LogManager.getLogger(). If I change the type of the Logger to this, then no instance of LogManager is being able to match this type of Logger. I tried using org.apache.log4j.LogManager and org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager, but they didn't return this type of Logger.

Comment: Ok. `org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager` have to return `org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger`. It has method `log(Level level, CharSequence message)`. Javadoc here https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-api/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/Logger.html

Comment: Thanks Alex. That gave me the required signature. However, I have not been able to test it yet as it's too late at night here. I will test it tomorrow and share the results with you.

Comment: Thanks so much, Alex for helping me cross that hurdle. I have a further question which I thought would not fit here as it's scope is much broader but still connected to this question. Please take a look at this question, and if you could please share your knowledge , I would be grateful. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62038779/log4j-logs-not-appearing-for-custom-log-levels-in-java-spark-program